# Forced line breaking in table with references

Tags: tables

I have a table with citations in it and I use apacite for citation. Here is a short example:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\tiny
\begin{center}
\caption{\textit{  }}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline 
Authors & Sample\\
\hline
\citeNP{Caroselli200613}    &   141 \\
\hline
\label{T:ControlGrPerf}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

When the reference in the first column is really long, the table doesn't fit the page. Is there a way to limit the size of a cell or to force line breaking within a reference?

I looked at other questions, but they all concern text within the cells where you can manually specifiy the line breaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\begin{tabular}{p{0.5\columnwidth}l}
```

This will typeset the citation as a justified paragraph with line length half the normal line length. Adjust to suit your needs.

If you prefer that the citation is typeset raggedright, then you must `\usepackage{array}` and the command will become

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.5\columnwidth}l}
```

Some words about your input. Never say `\begin{table}[h]`: if TeX is not able to place the table "there", it will postpone it to the end of the chapter together with all subsequent tables. The purpose of the `table` environment is to let them "float" in order to get good pagination.

Don't use the `center` environment in `table`, but rather the simple `\centering` declaration (put it in place of `\begin{center}` and delete `\end{center}`).

The `\label` command refers to the table. Its place is just after the `\caption` (and outside the `tabular` environment).

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution, although it works with regular tables, I could not use it for longtables. Do you have any idea/solution why it is like that? (I don't get any error it just does not work and I added array package)

Comment: @nooshinha I see no reason for `\begin{longtable}{>{\raggedright}p{0.5\columnwidth}l}` not working. Please open a new question with the details,